# limit the touchable area of UIbutton

Tags: ios, uibutton

This is how I set button navigation bar

```
 UIButton *addEditButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [addEditButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addEditButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 62, 31)]; used frame same as image

    [addEditButton addTarget:self action:@selector(EditTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *addEdit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addEditButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =addEdit;
```

Everything works perfectly but button get pressed when I touch out side of it. How to solve this is there any way so it get pressed only if I touch on it

This is that image [image]

Comment: set that image as background image, so that you can see actual frame of that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apple has set this thing in way so user can navigate smoothly. it is advisable not to make such design in which you are putting buttons near navigationBarButton. there are some way to do it but its not good to change this kind of things. its just like reply to message and delete message both button are near beside to each other

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you got this issue because the image you are setting is smaller thant the actual size of the button. please either make the button size smaller or provide a bigger image.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: i checked image size and then i set frame of button they both are same ashok

Comment: Iam sorry, Iam not pretty much expert in this, i donno if you have tried this already, but what i would do in this situation is that, i would try setting a background color to the button, so that the button bounds would be filed and i could ensure the given image fits inside the button. Did you try that as well prakash?

Comment: Thats ok, I will tell you, Please try this code,     [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; replace the button with your button name

Answer (score 0):

It seems it works like that only, still I came up with a solution.

One is you can hide your navigation bar and use a toolbar indeed.

Other is you can add another button after that and set it's enabled property to FALSE.

I don't know whether this is proper or not, but seems to fulfill your requirement at least.

Here is the code:

```
UIButton *addEditButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addEditButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 62, 31)];

[addEditButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[addEditButton addTarget:self action:@selector(EditTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *addEditButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[addEditButton1 setFrame:CGRectMake(63, 0, 30, 31)]; 

UIBarButtonItem *addEdit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addEditButton];
UIBarButtonItem *addEdit1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addEditButton1];
addEdit1.enabled = FALSE;


NSMutableArray *buttonArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
[buttonArray addObject:addEdit];
[buttonArray addObject:addEdit1];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems =buttonArray;
```

Comment: Hinata i dont understand why you did this all, why made that another button with different frame and add them in array and then leftbarbuttoniteam will you please explain this. i am nood i dont understand